# Yii2 render html tag inside translation string

Tags: internationalization, translation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a translatable string in **common/messages/en-Us/frontend/quicksignup** as:

```
return [
    'AcceptTermsAndConditionLabel' => 'I confirm that I am more than 13 years old and accept the {terms and condition}, and {privacy policy} of this website',
];
```

My **QuickSignupForm** model looks like:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
     return [
        'AcceptTermsAndCondition'   => Yii::t('frontend/quicksignup','AcceptTermsAndConditionLabel'),

     ];
}
```

It render the following content:

```
I confirm that I am more than 13 years old and accept the {terms and condition}, and {privacy policy} of this website
```

I want to replace the `{terms and condition}`and `{privacy policy}`with the links. But when I try to do that in my translatable file i.e **common/messages/en-Us/frontend/quicksignup** it gets rendered as a string.

Below is the screenshot of the output. How can I render the links? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find solution. Use `label` method in `ActiveField` and set `format=>raw` option. Code like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox()->label(Yii::t('app', 'I confirm that I am more than 13 years old and accept the {terms and condition}, and {privacy policy} of this website', ['privacy policy'=>
        Html::a('111', '/asd/')]), ['format' => 'raw']) ?>
```

This solution have one minus. You must set label twice: in model and in form.

Comment: Worked like charm :) Thanks a lot you saved my day!!